# Converting matrix into 128x128 picture

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I am pretty new to Matlab, and I am trying to convert my data file into an
128x128  matrix in order to display an image. So, in my file I have 3 columns with 16384 numeric values in each of them, and I need to have 128x128x3 matrix, like a format of image. I was trying method reshape, but it did not work for me, I am getting an error such

> Error using reshape
>
> To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Here is my code

```
x = load('out.txt');
B = reshape (x,128,128);
```

What would be the best solution for this problem?

Comment: A is now 1x16384, or the error would not happen

Comment: sorry, I changed the code, it will show it as 16384x3 double array, and how to convert it to 128x128 matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a 128x128x3 matrix, you have to say so to `reshape`:

```
B = reshape (x,128,128,3);
```

You can leave one of the values out, but you have to replace it with an empty array:

```
B = reshape (x,128,[],3);
```

This will calculate the size for that dimension.